# Print list elements with difference more than a value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a Python list.

```
x = [230, 235, 300, 480, 480, 506, 515, 516]
```

I want to print a list with elements from Array x, with difference of more than a value(lets assume 10). So the new list will contain only elements with difference of more than 10 than the next element. The output list should contain elements which have more than 10 difference with their adjacent element in the given list.
Output should be a list of [230, 300, 480, 516]

I want to make a function to make this possible.

```
b = [0] + x
t = []
for i in range(len(b)-1):
    if(b[i+1]-b[i]>10):
        t.append(b[i])

print(t)
```

I tried this. But I'm not getting proper output.

Comment: You can try `[k for k,v in zip(x, x[1:]) if v-k > 10]`

Comment: Can you paste your output here?

Comment: It outputs [0, 235, 300, 480]

Comment: This question is a little unclear. What do you want the output to be if you have a list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15] (assuming that you have a difference of 10)? Do you want the output to be [1, 15] or [1, 3, 5, 15]?

Comment: No. I need elements only if their difference is more than 10. In your given example, I need [1, 15] as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
a=[230,235,300,480,480,506,515,516]
b=[0]+a
c=[]
for i in range(0,len(b)-1):
        if((b[i+1]-b[i])>10):
                c.append(b[i+1])
print(c)
```

**Output:**

```
[230, 300, 480, 506]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. But is there a more pythonic way to do it?

Comment: I can't tell you that because I'm just a beginner, & has started learning python just 15days back.

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
xarr = np.array(x)
result = xarr[np.where(np.diff(xarr) > 10)[0]+1]
```

Produces:

```
array([300, 480, 506])
```

I believe this may be what you are looking for?

Comment: 230 is not in the result array. I need [230, 300, 480, 506] as output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print([k for k,v in zip(x, x[1:]) if abs(k-v) > 10])
```

`zip` is your friend.

Note: this works even with the list having up and down values (meaning some times large number, and sometimes small), because i use `abs`.

**Update:**

```
l=[(k,v) for k,v in zip(x[1:], x) if abs(k-v) >= 10]
print([list(zip(*l))[1][0]]+list(list(zip(*l))[0]))
```

Works to get desired output, it's your friend now.

Comment: The output for your code gives [235, 300, 480]. It does not print 506

Comment: @MoidShaikh Now?, i edited mine, hope well it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using iterators:

```
import itertools
def gapFilter(l, gap_value):
  it1, it2 = itertools.tee(l)
  next(it2)
  return [x for x, y in zip(it1, it2) if abs(x-y) >= gap_value]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/TinyNewSysadmin)

For getting the initial 0, just append it to the list before computing.
`Python3` example:

```
gapFilter([0, *x], 10)
```

Comment: Last element is not adding in the result